# Does Asp.net Identity rely on stored procedures or views?

Tags: sql-server, webforms, asp.net-identity, asp.net-membership

I have an application that used to work with membership. Now I switched to identity.

I can see the membership tables, stored procedures and views all over the place. They start with `asp.net_<Name of the table>`, `asp_net_<Name of the stored procedure>`, and `asp_net_<Name of the view>`.

For the identity, all I could find are 5 tables:

- `AspNetRoles`
- `AspNetUserLogins`
- `AspNetUserClaims`
- `AspNetUserRoles`
- `AspNetUsers`

I've searched folders in the database, but I can't confirm whether besides the above 5 tables, identity uses other objects, such as stored procedures or views.

If that's the case, can I just script those tables and the create them in the test database? So that when I try to log in, I don't get an error?

Thanks for helping

Comment: I believe identity only uses those tables. Nothing else.

Comment: I guess it's safe just to script those 5 of so tables. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Be aware that changes in code could end creating changes in the table schema, code first and all that. Really you should run an ef migration

Comment: This article is a bit dated but if you go over it you'll have a decent idea of what all is going on here with Identity framework and entity framework